# Writing a Ruby method in the model that outputs HTML in the view

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've got a method in my view that decides which HTML to print out depending on the class of the object it gets:

```
<% def laybricks(c,stream) %>
  <% if c.is_a?(Post) %>
    <article>
      // Tons more HTML unique to posts
    </article>
  <% elsif c.is_a?(Photograph) %>
    <article>
      // Tons more HTML unique to photographs
    </article>
  <% end %>
<% end>
```

But I now know more about Rails since writing it. How can I transfer this to my model so that I can call the method in the view and have it print the HTML the same?

Comment: this most probably belongs to a helper instead of a model

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Method in a view would definitely be better moved to the helper.

But for your need the best solution is **partials** utilizing some rails magic:

```
<%= render @c %>
```

will magically render partial `_post.html.erb` if `@c` is an instance of `Post` and `_photograph.html.erb` if it is instance of `Photograph`. These partials should be in the same view folder, and you can reference your object as `post` and `photograph` in each partial respectively.

For more info see [Rails Rendering Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html).

---

*ADDON:*

> How can I transfer this to my model so that I can call the method in the view and have it print the HTML

It is usually not a responsibility of a model to generate HTML, but if you ultimately want to do this, the best way is to use a design pattern that is usually referred to as Presenter or Decorator. E.g. `draper` gem exists for this, but also many other. And there is many discussions in Rails community how this pattern should be called, how it should be implemented and is it worth it at all.

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE:

**Application Helper**

```
def laybricks(c,stream) 
    content = []
      if c.is_a?(Post) 
       content << "<article> </article>"
      elsif c.is_a?(Photograph) 
       content << "<article> </article>"
      end 
end
```

**Your View**

```
<%= raw laybricks %>
```

OR

```
 <%= laybricks.html_safe %>
```

**NOTE:** The raw helper will allow the plain html to get interpreted. You can also use `html_safe` method to interpret the same.

Comment: 1. You cannot have plain html/erb in helpers (but can in partials)

2. All helpers from `app/helpers` are usually loaded into view context automatically, so no need in `@controller`

Comment: See the update. You can have `html/erb` in helpers but it is how you call raw in a view to interprete. Your second point is obvious for rails latest versions. In lower versions, you explicitly have to declare so in a controller.Thanks!

Comment: Helper is just a plain Ruby module, putting `<article>` in there is just a syntax error (yes, I tested it: `/home/vk/quails/app/helpers/application_helper.rb:35: syntax error, unexpected '<'
      <article>`). Maybe you are talking about partials, or some other kind of templates that allow combining html with ruby code... but definitely not vanilla rails helpers found in `app/helpers`. I would be happy to learn if this code works for you and how.

Comment: good to curious though. See the update. You can use `<article>` within qoutes as seen in above reply.Try.

Comment: Now I see, sure you can just construct a string. But your current example will return only `"</article>"` as every rails method only returns the last calculated value.

Comment: In addition it is not the best practice to construct html strings manually, at least one can use `content_tag` helper. And partials are ultimately the solution, if one needs to stuff there "tons of HTML" as it says.

Comment: you can try that if you notice that last else part is the html but not the only `</article>` that will render when you use html_safe or raw helper method. In the current scenario there are few html tags so here you can use it though in a helper.

Comment: tried it as soon as I have Post model in my app :) `> laybricks(Post.first, nil) => "</article>"` I mean, you have to concatenate strings, otherwise just the last line is returned.

Comment: Great! Updated my reply. Just see, you will surely get it now. :)

Comment: And of course using plain string + raw or html_safe is very insecure. It is easy to do something like `raw "<article>#{@post.body}</article>"`. And when a user puts some `<script>` tags in article body, they will be rendered and malicious js executed.

Comment: Ya I know but here in this code there is no `<script>` tag and it is pure html render by raw or html_safe. It is upto user what he/she wants. Here its ok.